# Luigi set config from within the code

Tags: python-3.6, luigi

I've wrapped a set of luigi task into a package. For now, each etl-task has it's own `luigi.cfg` in the same directory, however as all of those `.cfg` files are the same, it looks suboptimal. On top of that, I'd prefer to write S3 credentials from a different package/environmental var, rather than storing in flat files in git.

What is the best way to set default/general configuration for luigi from within package?

It looks like `luigi.Config` and `luigi.interface.core` packages are promising, but I am still not sure where I need to execute/initiate them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try using

```
luigi.configuration.get_config().set('core', 'some_key', 'some_value')
```

in a running instance.
You can access the same data using

```
luigi.configuration.get_config().get('core', 'some_key').
```